# fatal: Too many arguments. PowerPoint alters my git command

Tags: git

What I'm trying to do is to paste the git clone command which clones the `lectia1` branch of my repository.

The problem is that if I write (manually) this command it works like charm, I get the repo on my machine and everything is nice. Problems begin when I just paste the entire command copied from a PowerPoint slide into the git bash. (Don't ask why I need git clone links in a power point)

Pasting this command clones the repo -

`git clone -b lectia1 https://github.com/dorinbaba/apoo-papp1912`

But pasting this one

`git clone –b lectia1 https://github.com/dorinbaba/apoo-papp1912`

(which is copied from PowerPoint) doesn't, event if it may seem that there is absolutely no difference between them. I bet there is something ASCII related at the middle.

Is there an overcome for this? Thank you! (It's an empty repo, feel free to clone it)

Comment: It looks as if your `-` character (ASCII 45) was transformed into `–` (Unicode [en-dash](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2013/index.htm) character).

Comment: Yeah, this was the problem. The font that is being used in PowerPoint and the git bash default font displays these characters the same. Thank you!

Comment: Why do you need git clone links in a pow... er, never mind. :-) (I've hit similar Dilbertian things once or twice.)

Comment: File \ Options \ Proofing \ Autocorrect \ AutoFormat as you Type \ Replace as you type \ Hyphens with dashes = off. You may also want to turn off "Straight quotes with smart quotes".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured out the problem right after publishing the question. After a close analysis of those 2 links I realized that Microsoft PowerPoint changes the `-b` to `–b`, where `–` != `-`. StackOverflow's font offers the possibility to distinguish these two different characters.

So I have to look for a way to not allow PowerPoint to transform `-` to `–`.

Comment: Extra irony: my iPhone does the same sort of thing. When I type e.g. `--oneline` in an answer / comment on SO, I get a blasted em-dash.